# how do I move list elements in jQuery UI Sortable without the mouse, purely in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to just set up a link that allows the user to jump a given sortable list element to the top of the list. I need something like

```
$('.sortable li:last-child').move('.sortable li:first-child');
```

...where I can just cause a link to pop any list element up to the top of the list.

**Never mind! I found the answer.** $(id).prependTo($('#list'));

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's the best solution but this should work.

```
$('.sortable li:last-child').live('click', function() {
    $(this).prependTo('.sortable');
});
```

Kind of hard to help further without seeing more code.